# Is there a faster way to check if an external web page exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote this method to check if a page exists or not:

```
protected bool PageExists(string url)
{
try
    {
        Uri u = new Uri(url);
        WebRequest w = WebRequest.Create(u);

            w.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;

        using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(w.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return (s.ReadToEnd().Length >= 0);
        }
    }
        catch
    {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

I am using it to check a set of pages (iterates from AAAA-AAAZ), and it takes between 3 and 7 seconds to run the entire loop. Is there a faster or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is there a way to get at just the headers, and check for 200?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think your approach is rather good, but would change it into only downloading the headers by adding `w.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;` before calling `GetResponse`.

This could do it:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
bool pageExists = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

You may probably want to check for other status codes as well.

Comment: Exactly.  Why read all the way to the end when just the first view bytes will do.

Comment: @Viktor: good suggestion; I was writing the code sample while you gave it :o)

Comment: Currently trying this out, but when I put that in (added your line of code before the using statement) each one returns a 404 exception. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: @Fredrik - what other status codes should I check for? from the spec page ( http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html ), the only other one I can see that may apply is the 'Found' status.

Comment: @Anders: I was thinking about the redirect related ones (such as `HttpStatusCode.Redirect` and `HttpStatusCode.Moved`) which indicates that the content exists, but not at the requested URL. There may be others that you want to accept, depending on the purpose of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
static bool GetCheck(string address)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        return (response.Headers.Count > 0);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
static bool HeadCheck(string address)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        return (response.Headers.Count > 0);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Beware, certain pages (eg. WCF .svc files) may not return anything from a head request.  I know because I'm working around this right now.
EDIT - I know there are better ways to check the return data than counting headers, but this is a copy/paste from stuff where this is important to us.

Comment: Oh yeah, and you can refactor to a single method that takes "GET" or "HEAD" as a param, if you wanted to be all efficient as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious speedup is to run several requests in parallel - most of the time will be spent on IO, so spawning 10 threads to each check a page will complete the whole iteration around 10 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could do it using asynchronous way, because now you are waiting for results after each request. For few pages, you could just throw your function in ThreadPool, and wait for all requests to finish. For more requests, you could use asynchronous methods for your ResponseStream() (BeginRead etc.).
2. The other thing that can help you (help me for sure) is to clear `.Proxy` property:

```
w.Proxy = null;
```

Without this, at least 1st request is much slower, at least on my machine.
3. You can not download whole page, but download only header, by setting .Method to "HEAD".

Answer (score -2):

I simply used Fredrik Mörk answer above but placed it within a method:

```
private bool checkURL(string url)
        {
            bool pageExists = false;
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                pageExists = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Do what ever you want when its no working...
                //Response.Write( e.ToString());
            }
            return pageExists;
        }
```