# Download image from the site in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, streaming

I am trying to download images from the site. The code which I am using is working fine while the image is available. If the image it not available it is creating a problem. How to validate availability of the image?

Code:

Method 1:

```
WebRequest requestPic = WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);

WebResponse responsePic = requestPic.GetResponse();

Image webImage = Image.FromStream(responsePic.GetResponseStream()); // Error

webImage.Save("D:\\Images\\Book\\" + fileName + ".jpg");
```

Method 2:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(imageUrl);

bitmap = new Bitmap(stream); // Error : Parameter is not valid.
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
client.dispose();

if (bitmap != null)
{
    bitmap.Save("D:\\Images\\" + fileName + ".jpg");
}
```

**Edit:**

Stream has the following statements:

```
      Length  '((System.Net.ConnectStream)(str)).Length' threw an exception of type  'System.NotSupportedException'    long {System.NotSupportedException}
    Position  '((System.Net.ConnectStream)(str)).Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'    long {System.NotSupportedException}
 ReadTimeout  300000    int
WriteTimeout  300000    int
```

Comment: Wrap the offending statement with `try - catch`, and provide us with exception details.

Comment: the line  bitmap = new Bitmap(stream); shows error: Parameter is not valid.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

There is no need to involve any image classes, you can simply call [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx):

```
string localFilename = @"c:\localpath\tofile.jpg";
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/image.jpg", localFilename);
}
```

---

**Update**
Since you will want to check whether the file exists and download the file if it does, it's better to do this within the same request. So here is a method that will do that:

```
private static void DownloadRemoteImageFile(string uri, string fileName)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    // Check that the remote file was found. The ContentType
    // check is performed since a request for a non-existent
    // image file might be redirected to a 404-page, which would
    // yield the StatusCode "OK", even though the image was not
    // found.
    if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || 
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved || 
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
        response.ContentType.StartsWith("image",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {

        // if the remote file was found, download oit
        using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

In brief, it makes a request for the file, verifies that the response code is one of `OK`, `Moved` or `Redirect` *and also* that the `ContentType` is an image. If those conditions are true, the file is downloaded.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the `WebClient`.

Comment: @Geetha: do you get an image if you try to navigate to the given URL in a web browser?

Comment: @Geetha: it sounds as if you would first want to check if the image exists, then download it. For that first step, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379371/c-is-there-a-faster-way-to-check-if-an-external-web-page-exists

Comment: It is taking too much of time and also downloading blank image. the line bitmap = new Bitmap(stream); shows error: Parameter is not valid

Comment: "There is no need to involve any image classes". Actually there is a need if you're intention is download an image, manipulate it and simply display it. There is no need to store a file or even fill up a disk with images if there is no need to store the file.

Answer (score 26):

I have used Fredrik's code above in a project with some slight modifications, thought I'd share:

```
private static bool DownloadRemoteImageFile(string uri, string fileName)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse response;
    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Check that the remote file was found. The ContentType
    // check is performed since a request for a non-existent
    // image file might be redirected to a 404-page, which would
    // yield the StatusCode "OK", even though the image was not
    // found.
    if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
        response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {

        // if the remote file was found, download it
        using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead != 0);
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Main changes are:

- using a try/catch for the GetResponse() as I was running into an exception when the remote file returned 404
- returning a boolean

Comment: thank you - looks like well written code and works well in my application

Comment: Why return a boolean flag when you can throw an exception? It's always better until you have performance problems. SRP does not allow to have these methods.

Answer (score 5):

Also possible to use DownloadData method

```
    private byte[] GetImage(string iconPath)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            byte[] pic = client.DownloadData(iconPath);
            //string checkPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +@"\1.png";
            //File.WriteAllBytes(checkPath, pic);
            return pic;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        private static void DownloadRemoteImageFile(string uri, string fileName)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
                response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
            {
                using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    } while (bytesRead != 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain this code, and _why_ it works?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to download an image from Server or from Website and store it locally.

```
WebClient client=new Webclient();
client.DownloadFile("WebSite URL","C:\\....image.jpg");
client.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
                    Stream stream = client.OpenRead(imgUrl);
                    if (stream != null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
                        ImageFormat imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                        if (bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Png)) {
                            imageFormat = ImageFormat.Png;
                        }
                        else if (bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Bmp)) {
                            imageFormat = ImageFormat.Bmp;
                        }
                        else if (bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Gif)) {
                            imageFormat = ImageFormat.Gif;
                        }
                        else if (bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Tiff)) {
                            imageFormat = ImageFormat.Tiff;
                        }

                        bitmap.Save(fileName, imageFormat);
                        stream.Flush();
                        stream.Close();
                        client.Dispose();
                    }
                }
```

Project available at: [github](https://github.com/ranjit-singh-cc/DownloadImagesByUrl)