# save images from url

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to save images using `Visual Basic 2008` from URL to my PC?

**For example** : From `www.domain.com/image.jpg` to `C:\folder\image.jpg`

P.S: I need simpliest example of the code, then I will edit is as I need.

Thanks.

**Update : I want to know when the code have finished downloading of the image.**

Comment: Check this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615800/download-image-from-the-site-in-net-c][1]

The same classes are available for VB

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615800/download-image-from-the-site-in-net-c

Comment: Check out the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) / [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes, or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the simplest way I know.

```
Dim Client as new WebClient
Client.DownloadFile(Source, Destination)
Client.Dispose
```

This is superior to using the My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile method per Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y(v=vs.90).aspx)

"The DownloadFile method does not send optional HTTP headers. Some servers may return 500 (Internal Server Error) if the optional user agent header is missing. To send optional headers, you must construct a request using the WebClient class."

Comment: looks really easy =) It will wait image to be downloaded and the will execute next code, or I will only send request and will execute next code?

Comment: It is synchronous, so it will wait until the file is downloaded before continuing.

Comment: You should use "Using". Your code does the same, but it's much "safer" as it directly shows you that you haven't forgotten anything.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler way:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(Source, Desination)
```

Comment: I love how simple this is!

Comment: @WilliamContestabile There is a reason to use my solution over this solution. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here what i came up with.

```
 Public Function getImgFrmUrl(ByVal url As String, ByVal Optional ImageName As String = "", ByVal Optional DstntnPath As String = "c:\") As String

        Dim imgPath = DstntnPath & "\"
        Dim name = IIf(ImageName.Length = 0, Guid.NewGuid.ToString, ImageName)
        Dim fileExt = Path.GetExtension(url)

        Using webClient As WebClient = New WebClient
            Const _Tls12 As SslProtocols = CType(&HC00, SslProtocols)
            Const Tls12 As SecurityProtocolType = CType(_Tls12, SecurityProtocolType)
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12
            Dim data As Byte() = webClient.DownloadData(url)
            If File.Exists(imgPath + name & fileExt) Then File.Delete(imgPath + name & fileExt)

            Using mem = New MemoryStream(data)

                Using yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem)

                    If fileExt.ToLower Is ".png" Then
                        yourImage.Save(imgPath + name & fileExt, ImageFormat.Png)
                    Else
                        yourImage.Save(imgPath + name & fileExt, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        Return imgPath & name & fileExt
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

create a module and use this function

Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Public Function DownloadFile(sURLFile As String, sLocalFilename As String) As Boolean
    Dim lRetVal As Long
    lRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, sURLFile, sLocalFilename, 0, 0)
    If lRetVal = 0 Then DownloadFile = True
End Function

Comment: If you [edit] your answer and apply a little [formatting], it will improve it a great deal.