# How to apply a texture from a picture to a text

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have tried to google for hours in attempt to get a way to apply a texture picture in a string, like for example:

I have a string and I want to apply a pattern or a texture into the string.
Is there any way to do it in VB 2012?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Start by looking at the `GraphicsPath` class.

Comment: You should give more information. What technology are you using (winforms, Unity, ...)? Are you drawing on a Form on a bitmap, something else? What have you tried so far? Please show some code. (Then maybe your question will be upvoted again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a string by using a texture brush.

This example draws into a label of a winforms form (could be any other control or the form itself

```
Private Sub Label1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Label1.Paint
    Dim fileName = "C:\somepath\myImage.png"

    Dim image1 = Image.FromFile(fileName, True)

    Dim texture As New TextureBrush(image1)
    texture.WrapMode = Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile

    Dim font As New Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold)

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello", font, texture, 10, 10)
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i have try your example but its seems not work for me i send the print i have only change the directory of my photo https://imgur.com/a/SSGnCe8

Comment: This only works for an image on the local storage (hard-disk). Try that first. See this code for downloading an image from the web: [save images from url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9689105/880990)

Comment: Tanks For The Great Help

Comment: how can i save it as png ?

Comment: See: [Create and Save Bitmap Image in VB.NET?](https://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/create-and-save-bitmap-image-in-vb.net).