# How to save Image Control Image in Folder in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I know how to save an image to a folder using the fileupload control with the saveas method. But I to take an image from the image control and save it to a file without using the fileupload control n save it in folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string filepath = img1.ImageUrl;           
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
       client.DownloadFile(filepath,Server.MapPath("~/Image/apple.jpg"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know image path? you can get image path from image control and then download image in code:

[Download image from the site in .NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615800/download-image-from-the-site-in-net-c)

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/image.jpg", localFilename); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First Get the Url of Image and then using webclient you can save file in folder

```
string filepath = img1.ImageUrl;           
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
       client.DownloadFile(filepath,Server.MapPath("~/Image/apple.jpg"));
}
```

This will save image in Image Folder with ImageName apple...