# Save image from URL to local hard drive using C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to write a console application in order to store a single image from a given path into a new directory as suggested in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx). Despite my program not throwing out any errors the image I want to download just won't show up in my folder. I guess that's because I never told my program where I want the file to be saved? However, I haven't found anything clarifying this particular problem I have right now. I already referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110246/how-do-i-programmatically-save-an-image-from-a-url) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696185/how-to-save-image-control-image-in-folder-in-asp-net) question, too.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace GetImages
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirPath = @"C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Images";

        try
        {
            // Create a new directory
            DirectoryInfo imageDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
            Console.WriteLine($"Directory '{Path.GetFileName(dirPath)}' was created successfully in {Directory.GetParent(dirPath)}");

            // Image I'm trying to download from the web
            string filePath = @"http://ilarge.lisimg.com/image/12056736/1080full-jessica-clements.jpg";

            using (WebClient _wc = new WebClient())
            {
                _wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(filePath), Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                _wc.Dispose();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nFile successfully saved.");
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            while (e != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                e = e.InnerException;
            }
        }            

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Edit:** After some time I figured out that the file is saved in `"C:\Users\Stefan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GetImages\GetImages\bin\Debug"`. But how do I get the file to be saved directly to `dirPath` without moving them from `Debug` to `dirPath` separately? My next step would be extending this program to save multiple files at once.

Comment: First of all you don't need `_wc.Dispose();` as you are using `using (WebClient _wc = new WebClient())` which will do it automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of DownloadFileAsync is the save location so combine the path you create and the filename from the URL:

```
_wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(filePath), Path.Combine(dirPath, Path.GetFileName(filePath)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (WebClient _wc = new WebClient())
            {
                _wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(filePath), Path.Combine(dirPath,Path.GetFileName(filePath)));

            }
```