# System.NullReferenceException in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

Based upon a previous written [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219086/save-image-from-url-to-local-hard-drive-using-c-sharp/44219235#44219235) I'm now trying to store multiple images at once from a certain subreddit into a local directory. My Problem is that I can't get my LINQ statement working properly. I also don't want to download the thumbnail pictures which was why I took a look at the HTML-page and found out that the links I aim to retrieve are hidden in level 5 within the `href` attribute:

```
(...)
Level 1: <div class="content">...</div>
    Level 2: <div class="spacer">...</div>
        Level 3: <div class="siteTable">...</div>
            Level 4: <div class=" thing id-t3_6dj7qp odd  link ">...</div>                      
                Level 5: <a class="thumbnail may-blank outbound" href="href="http://i.imgur.com/jZ2ZAyk.jpg"">...</a>
```

That was my best bet in line '???':

```
.Where(link => Directory.GetParent(link).Equals(@"http://i.imgur.com"))
```

Sadly enough it throws out an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) stating that

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Well now I know why it's not working but I've still got no clue how to rewrite this line since I'm still fairly new to Lambda Expressions. To be honest, I don't really know why I got a `System.NullReferenceException` in the first place but not in the next line. What's the difference? Maybe my approach on this problem isn't even good practice at all so please let me know how I could proceed further.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace GetAllImages
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> imageLinks = new List<string>();

            // Specify Directory manually
            string dirName = "Jessica Clements";
            string rootPath = @"C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop";
            string dirPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, dirName);

            // Specify the subReddit manually
            string subReddit = "r/Jessica_Clements";
            string url = @"https://www.reddit.com/" + subReddit;

            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo imageFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);                

                HtmlDocument document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
                imageLinks = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                            .Select(element => element.GetAttributeValue("href", null))
                            .Where(???) 
                            .Where(stringLink => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringLink))
                            .ToList();

                foreach(string link in imageLinks)
                {
                    using (WebClient _wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        _wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), Path.Combine(dirPath, Path.GetFileName(link)));
                    }                        
                 }

            Console.WriteLine($"Files successfully saved in '{Path.GetFileName(dirPath)}'.");             

            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                while(e != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    e = e.InnerException;
                }
             }

            if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Just in case someone is interested in this solution that's how I made it work in the end using the answers below:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
imageLinks = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
            .Select(element => element.GetAttributeValue("href", null))
            .Where(link => (link?.Contains(@"http://i.imgur.com") == true))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

Comment: A much better approach to your problem is to use the [JSON API](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jessica_Clements/.json) instead of parsing HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that this line throws the exception:

```
.Where(link => Directory.GetParent(link).Equals(@"http://i.imgur.com"))
```

I'd make sure that `link` is not null and that the result of `GetParent(link)` is not null either. So you could do:

```
.Where(link => link != null && (Directory.GetParent(link)?.Equals(@"http://i.imgur.com") ?? false))
```

Notice the null check and the `?.` after `GetParent()`. This one stops the execution of the term if null is returned from `GetParent()`. It is called the [Null Conditional Operator](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/06/17/nullconditionaloperator/) or "Elvis Operator" because it can be seen as two eyes with twirly hair. The `?? false` gives the default value in case the execution was stopped because of a null value.

**However**, if you plan to parse HTML code you should definitely have a look at the [Html Agility Pack (HAP)](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Comment: I've got a new idea: how about I swap both Where statements? That way wouldn't I ensure that link couldn't possibly be null? I'm mobile now so I can't check whether that's true or not.

Comment: Yeah, perfectly right. Skip the null check then and go for the elvis operator. Alternatively, use `String.Equals(link, "...")`. By not using the variable `link` to call methods on, you cannot run into NullRefs

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to get all links pointing to the http://i.imgur.com, you need something like this

```
    imageLinks = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                .Select(element => element.GetAttributeValue("href", null))
                .Where(link => link?.Contains(@"http://i.imgur.com") == true)
                .ToList();
```