# Upload Image from URI to Azure BLOB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-blob-storage

I'd like to upload images from an uri postet to an asp.net mvc5 controller to azure blob storage. I already got it working with HttpPostedFileBase, like this. Can I somehow get the memory stream from an image uri?

```
HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
var imgFile = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(hpf.InputStream, true, true);
CloudBlockBlob blob = coversContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("img.jpg");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
imgFile.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
stream.Position = 0;
blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
```

Comment: You can use a webclient do download the data and return it as MemoryStream(data)

Comment: thanks for pointing me into the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I managed to get it done:

```
public static Image DownloadRemoteImage(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response;
    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Check that the remote file was found. The ContentType
    // check is performed since a request for a non-existent
    // image file might be redirected to a 404-page, which would
    // yield the StatusCode "OK", even though the image was not
    // found.
    if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
        response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // if the remote file was found, download it
        Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        Image img = Image.FromStream(inputStream);
        return img;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code snipped was taken and modified from this question's answer:
[Download image from the site in .NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615800/download-image-from-the-site-in-net-c)