# Saving images from IP Camera to folder in application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a camera connected to a network that provides images which can be accessed by IP. For example something like this.

```
http://170.1.2.3/image?camera=2
```

I get returned a jpg file, which I can easily display back on a webpage using normal html.

```
<img src="http://170.1.2.3/image?camera=2" />
```

But instead of simply showing the camera image as seen from the time of the page load, I also want to save this image locally to the server using an MVC4 application. In addition it would be nice to include a timestamp on the filename. I'm not having any luck finding an example that looks right to me.

Let's say I want to start with the most basic example:

```
string imgUrl = "http://170.1.2.3/image?camera=2";
savelocally(imgurl, "newfilename-"+DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

.. and savelocally() should place the file in "~/Uploads". How do I do this? All the examples I've come across have been for uploading a file from desktop. I don't know how to translate that into grabbing a remote image.

**Update:**

This is an incomplete answer, as pointed out by comments.

```
string url = "http://170.1.2.3/image?camera=2";
string localFilename = @"C:\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Uploads\tofile.jpg";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(url, localFilename);
}
```

It works, however I don't like the fact that the file path is an absolute one. I tried replacing localFilename with ~/Uploads/tofile.jpg but it results in an error on execution. If possible I want to avoid having a fixed location for the upload folder.

Comment: I don't understand why someone would want to edit my post yet not actually change anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download image from the site in .NET/C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615800/download-image-from-the-site-in-net-c)

Comment: I had a look at that link. It saves the image to the hard drive, but I wasn't able to direct it to a folder in the web app. Also "File.OpenWrite" is not valid for some reason.

Comment: Updated the question post.