# Download image from Wikimedia

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, musicbrainz

I've read some documentation and after some research im not sure if there is an easy way to do this.

I am using MusicBrainz to get an image of an artist. Which produces this URL

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Michael_Jackson_in_1988.jpg

I would like to download the image (**which i have worked out**) but i dont know how or what the correct procedure would be?

I have read a few links and all seem to be pretty dated including:

[Download image from the site in .NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615800/download-image-from-the-site-in-net-c)

which doesnt answer my question as i already have a way of downloading the image. What im after in this case is a way of getting to the image URL using the above link which contains the download links.

I did read a link which is targeting an API but again that was dated and ready the help pages didnt mention this API (so it could have been third party).

I have everything to download the image, its just getting the correct URL which can be found on the link i posted above but i dont know how to extract the URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download image from the site in .NET/C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615800/download-image-from-the-site-in-net-c)

Comment: Have you tried parsing the HTML to find the absolute source of the embedded image?

Comment: Did a quick google but not entirely sure what steps i need to take? Could you possibly provide me a link to read up on?

Comment: @DLeh: have you read the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to get all the `<a href` elements in the html page and then look for the ones with an image type extension.

```
var document= new HtmlWeb().Load("https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Michael_Jackson_in_1988.jpg");
var allhrefs = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
```

I'm sure they share a common structure, <strike>so I'll let you figure that out</strike>. At a quick glance it looks like the very first `<a href` points to the raw image.

```
var imagelink = allhrefs.FirstOrDefault();
```

**EDIT**: If you want to be more careful, you can filter then nodes by looking for the `class='fullImageLink'` div with `id='file'`. This seems to host the `<a href` to the original image.