# Can't download image to client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have base64 string of an image. converting it to byte array & then converting it to memoryStream. How can i download this image to client machine. The base64 string or image is not saved on server/folder/anywhere. It is create dynamically. I have tried

1) Response.ContentType = "image/png" => gives exception obj not set to instant of an object. like this

```
Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.ClearHeaders();
Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + registrationId + ".png");
Context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
//Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

2) using web client => gives exception

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(ms1.ToString(), registrationId + ".png");
}
```

**Any other solution?**

Comment: How about [germankiwi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12631127/5588347)?

Comment: Why are you using `Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());` without `Context.`?

Comment: In second scenario you just try download file to server. It doesn't work.

Comment: give me code guys..

Comment: Can you post stacktrace?

Comment: @GraDea ...It works now..my page was not able to run above code..so finally i call another page & in that OnPageLoad() i ran above code..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
```

to

```
Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
```

I think you doesn't have valid `Page` object in this context.

Comment: @GraDea...got error on what you have suggested..  "Value does not fall within the expected range."