# How to use the ImageUrl property?

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I want to show products using TileView, but I do not show pictures when I give url. How can I overcome this problem?

```
private void tileView1_ItemCustomize(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Tile.TileViewItemCustomizeEventArgs e)
{
    TileView view = sender as TileView;
    string ID = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "ID").ToString();.ToString();
    string url = "http://webpage.com/images/"+ ID + ".jpg";
    e.Item.Elements[6].ImageUri = url;
}
```

Comment: URI is not the same as URL, one is web, the other is not necessarily so.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure for devexpress, hopefully somebody can tell you if they can take a URL as a URI.

Comment: It does not. it normally does not give an error when assigning a URI string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to using `URI` is this:

```
e.Item.Elements[6].ImageUri = new Uri(url);
```

The problem in your case might be that the image must first be downloaded in order for the control to use it.  So you're probably going to have to do something like this first:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615831/1633308

and then, instead of your `URI` being the web address, it would be the local image file (probably in temporary storage that you clean up later).