# httpwebrequests speed

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am using the httpwebrequest class to download the header information of pages to see if a page exists. So I am setting the method to head and using multiple threads. 
However I am only getting up to 1,000 requests per 30 seconds.

I've gone through and optimized everything I could. 
I set the proxy to null to avoid the check and the timeout worked best at 20000ms.

Also System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit was increased to the amount of threads used (which is 50).

All I need to check is if the page exists (404 or not), is there anything else that I can do to improve the speed?

An alternative I used was webclient, but I was unable to set it to head only.

Here is what I use now

```
HttpWebRequest req;

HttpWebResponse response;

bool ret;


req = WebRequest.Create("http://" + url) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = "HEAD";
req.Timeout = timeout;
req.Proxy = null;

response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
ret = (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Also, more threads often make things worse, not better. If you're using .NET 4.0 or above, then try using the `Task` class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Is there a faster way to check if an external web page exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379371/c-is-there-a-faster-way-to-check-if-an-external-web-page-exists)

Comment: Do you have to prove that the page exists or is it enough to know the server exists?

Comment: john I am using .NET 3.5 for compatibility purposes, what makes the task class more efficient than threads? @M.Babcock I need confirmation that the page exists

Comment: @John - John Saunders point is that having more threads than can be concurrently handled by the processor can actually _harm_ your performance. In 3.5, you should be using the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: Just spawning more threads causes problems with contention and use of resources. The `Task` class in .NET 4.0 manages the use of threads based on what the tasks are doing, in order to optimize the use of threads for the particular computer the application is running on. As @M.Babcock said, in .NET 3.5, your best bet is to use the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I switched it over to using a threadpool and it now runs three times slower.

Comment: What do you mean, "for compatibility purposes"? Also, you should be placing your `WebResponse` into a `using` block, since it implements `IDisposable`. Maybe you're slowing down due to resources not cleaned up.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It means that that 4.0 is not available on all computers. Rather than send extra files or force an update. I will keep it at 3.5. I set it to dispose the response on the spot and it slowed the requests by 40%

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the maximum connections in connection management.

Here is how you do it:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address = "http://www.contoso.com" maxconnection = "4" />
      <add address = "*" maxconnection = "2" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx)

Comment: Testing, keep in mind that I am checking millions of different domains

Comment: Tested, no visible speed improvement